# JavaFX-8 FileChooser Image (backend copy-paste)

Tags: java, image, javafx-8, filechooser

This is only the second question I have ever posted here on Stack Overflow, so hey guys! (please be gentle).

The next step in the project I'm doing involves files and the FileChooser library. Say I got the FileChooser to work, and that on a button click, the FileChooser opens and you can select the image you want.

Now say that the image comes from a flash drive plugged in to the computer. After taking the image, the filepath is stored into the database for later retrieval. But the problem, is that the filepath will be rendered useless when the flashdrive is plugged out.

Is there any way that to do a behind the scenes copy-paste of the image to the program's directory, so that I only need to take the filename, and append that to the default varchar value (proper directory minus filename) of the filepath column in the database?

I may be wording this wrong. This is in JavaFX-8 by the way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use `Files.copy` to copy the **file** from one location to the other, if that's what you want

Comment: Wow... that was fast. Will try this... Can't believe I missed this... Will get back in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

```
Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

**Note**: `source` and `destination` are references of [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html). Also, [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) is located in the package `java.nio.file`

Comment: Thank you for the help! God... Java is a cruel mistress.

Answer (score 0):

```
    File source = new File("path//myimage.jpg");
    File dest = new File("myimage.jpg");
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("DP Report Template File is not there");
    }
```

This will copy the file to your program directory.

Comment: Apache huh. I'll have to include the jar, I will try this, this looks promising. Will report in a bit.

Comment: you can add "org.apache.commons.io" jar.